# Orchard CMS Blog View / Layout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, orchardcms

I'm new to Orchard CMS & MVC so please take this into account. Any help -the more the better- will be greatly received.

I want to add widgets to my blog summary page. What is the best way to achieve this? Ive tried creating a layer for the blog summary page defined by the rules for the layer, so as to be unique to this page. However, this only allows me to add widgets into the layer zones.

What i need/want to do is to effectively create a side bar with a tag cloud and a blogroll showing titles of other posts, and a couple of other bits of content. This would mean moving the blog summary content into another zone inorder that i can fit widgets down the side.

Is this the correct approach? If so how do i shift the summary stuff into another zone??
If this isnt the best approach, what is???

Is this where projections come in???

Thanks

Comment: Show us some code. Also, what have you tried so far ?

Comment: @KPL Ive tried various things. I was hoping for some pointers from people who know more than me. I wasnt expecting to have to prove my worth. If that is what you expect, then I would question why you bother to come here. Its a valid question, and Im keen to learn. I have a 1st class degree in Multimedia & Internet Technology and won the Science, Computing & Engineering Departmental Prize for being highest acheiver. Does that earn the right to ask questions or do I have to do a merry dance to win the kings favour?

Comment: It's not that you have to prove your worth or show credentials, it's that your questions need to be a little more specific if you want to get specific answers. We all want to help, so let us. Congratulations on the degrees ;)

Comment: I don't understand why you feel you've been attacked... unless a comment was deleted before I got here, the only thing anyone asked was for more detail about what you've tried so far.

Comment: Can you please restate the question? I didn't quite understood which of the 2 things you're trying to accomplish - 1. show some widgets in the sidebar while the blog summary is shown (and be specific what kind of widgets and are they in any way related to the blog, or are they completely unrelated); or 2. you're trying to display a list of latest blog posts (and tag cloud and some other widgets (which?)) throughout the site?

Comment: @Paul, I was trying to ask what I thought was a simple question with a set means to achieve my goal. I didnt want to tarnish the question by going over the numerous areas of mis-educated stumbling that I'd done to this point. However, it seems this was the wrong approach.

Comment: @Ivan Feric No 1 is more in line with my requirements. I want / need to show the blog summary but with some as yet undetermined widget down the side of the blog summary. Rather than the blog summary taking up the full width of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I was able to find the relevant view then switch the zones around so that the narrower zone appeared on the right. Then created a projection to return the blog post summary and placed this in the left hand larger zone.

Thanks to everyone that tried to help. I knew there had to be a simple answer, hence my initially simplified question. I didnt realise that would cause so much grief.

Answer (score 4):

from my understanding of your question, my answer goes like this.

If you are using the default ThemeMachine, the 'main content' i.e your Blog Summary Page, gets loaded into the Content Zone - which is in the middle container or zone of the ThemeMachine, and is flanked by two Aside Zones or commonly known as sidebars. To achieve what you are wanting I would place both the Tag Cloud widget and Blogroll widget into either the left Aside/Sidebar or right, depending on the look you are after.

And that's it!

Now this is dependent on the Theme you are using and that the Aside Zone(s) is actually available for use which is dictated by the Theme manifest, which is a Theme.txt file in the root of the Theme.

Now if you are wanting to set rules for when those widgets are shown, you can do this using Layers in the Widgets area in the Admin Dashboard. Details on that will require a second question ;-) as I've hopefully answered your first.

P.S. Projections can be used to substitute for both the Blog Summary Page and Blog widget. And can give finer control on what gets displayed.

Comment: Hi Beast. Im using another template which would require me to move the blog summary to another zone which does have anotrher zone adhacent to it to allow positioning of the required widgets. Unfortunatey the content zone on my theme doesnt have any zone either side of it.

Comment: It sounds like you've created an Alternate Template for the Blog Summary, to create an Sidebar within the Alternate itself, which the Theme has not given you. I suggest any of the option in @Ivan Ferić answer below. As adding an Aside Zone in the Alternate will not expose that zone in the Admin Dashboard for you to place and manage widgets in. Better to go into the Theme itself and create the required Zone there and recommend you use **@Display(Model.Sidebar)** as in case **@Zone** is  removed/changed by the Theme developer. Highly unlikely though.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. However, I think I might have not explained myself very well. My theme has the zones in a different arrangement to the default theme. I assume the blog summary will be displayed in the 'content' zone ?? If so, I cannot place anything along side it, as the aside zones are below the content xone. Here is a visualisation of the content areas/zones: http://tuning.bind.pt/step_2.aspx?theme=+JZsMFhcs5RaSGggK3Kngw==&page=Zones.html

Answer (score 2):

I think I now understand what you're trying to accomplish and the solution requires you to modify your theme in one of two ways, whichever is most acceptable:

---

The first one is more preferable way but requires more work to be done. You should modify the `Layout.cshtml` template to split current `Content` zone in 2 - `Content` and `Aside`. This relies heavily on the current code of the template but it'll probably require changing from:

```
<section id="content-area">
    @Zone(Model.Content)
</section>
```

to:

```
<section id="content-area">
    @Zone(Model.Content)
</section>
@if(Model.Aside != null){
<aside id="aside-area">
    @Zone(Model.Aside)
</aside>
}
```

Next, you'll need to change CSS so that your `content-area` is floating on the left, and the `aside-area` is floating to the right.

You'll also need to change `Theme.txt` file of your theme to add `Aside` in the list of zones.

You can now add widgets to the `Aside` zone. If those widgets should be shown only in specific circumstances, you'll have to make additional layer(s) that will be active for those circumstances when you want the widgets to be shown.

---

The second solution is for case you want those widgets to be shown **only** when the the blog is shown in summary mode. This solution is not a regular way of using Orchard, but rather a trick that Orchard allows but is not designed with this in mind. Nonetheless, I find it useful in certain cases, so here it goes.

Change `Theme.txt` to add `Aside` zone in the list of zones.

Create a new template in your theme and name it `Content-Blog.cshtml`. Edit it so that it has this content:

```
<section id="content-area">
    @Display(Model.Content)
</section>
@if(Layout.Aside != null){
<aside id="aside-area">
    @Display(Layout.Aside)
</aside>
}
```

You'll also have to make CSS changes to set your `Aside` zone to the right side of the content.

Now you can add your widgets to the `Aside` zone. Note that now you don't have to make new layers because the only time the `Aside` zone is shown is when the `Content-Blog.cshtml` is rendered and it's rendered only when showing `Blog` in summary mode.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. However, I think I might have not explained myself very well. My theme has the zones in a different arrangement to the default theme. I assume the blog summary will be displayed in the 'content' zone ?? If so, I cannot place anything along side it, as the aside zones are below the content xone. Here is a visualisation of the content areas/zones: http://tuning.bind.pt/step_2.aspx?theme=+JZsMFhcs5RaSGggK3Kngw==&page=Zones.html

Comment: Yes, blog summary will be displayed in the 'content' zone. But you can modify 'Content-Blog.cshtml' like I proposed in the second solution. This way, you will effectively create 'Aside' zone that will appear only when displaying blog in summary mode. And you can change the CSS so that 'Aside' zone appears on the right (or left) of the blog summary..

Comment: Thanks. Ive decided to create a projection and put that in the appropriate content zone for simplicity. It gave me a need to explorer projections and queries, ;-)